# How to send mail when apply a leave

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I want to send mail when an employee applies for a leave.Now the mail is sent when clicks the approve button. I want to sent the mail when leave is created. How to achieve this functionality? I'm working on Odoo version 10

Comment: are you trying to send main by python code or there is a trigger is in oddo application......

Comment: I didn't write any customized code. By default odoo is sending mail when I approve the leave . I want the same thing to be happened when leave is created @PuneetSinha

Comment: This needs code customisation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code for sending email in def create(self, vals):

create your own email template and then add this code in your create method.

```
self.env['mail.template'].browse(your email template).send_mail(obj.id)
```

i hope this will help you.!